# Using spread element to merge values in reduce of a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array - `types` - which looks something like this -

```
[
  {"id": 1, "name": "Payment"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Debit"},
  {"id": 3, "name": "Credit"},
  {"id": 4, "name": "Transaction"}
]
```

I want to transform the array into another array which looks like this -

```
[
  {"Payment": 1},
  {"Debit": 2},
  {"Credit": 3},
  {"Transaction": 4}
]
```

---

When I do the following, the first entry is always missing  -

```
const typeArray = types === null || types.length === 0 ? [] :
    types.map((type) => {
        const id = type.id;
        const name = type.name;
        return {[name]: id};
    })
        .reduce((prev, curr) => [...prev, curr]);
```

I always get the output something like this -

```
[
  {"Debit": 2},
  {"Credit": 3},
  {"Transaction": 4}
]
```

---

When I instead use -

```
    .reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, curr]);
```

I get a nested array, but all the elements are present. The array looks like so -

```
[
   [
      [
        {"Payment":1},
        {"Debit":2}
      ],
      {"Credit":3}
   ],
   {"Transaction":4}
]
```

How do I do this. Is there something like `flatMap()` from `RxJS` where I can merge all the arrays into a single array?

Comment: Basically, remove the `.reduce((prev, curr) => [...prev, curr]);` line, as 200 answers will tell you.

Comment: Yes you are right, is there a way to think about it - times when to use `map` and `map-reduce`.

Comment: `.reduce` is usually used if you want a __single__ "aggregated" value from an array. `.map` is used if you want a resulting array of the same length, where every "row" has been modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `map` method which accepts as parameter a **callback** function in order to obtain a `cleaner` solution.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
let array=[
  {"id": 1, "name": "Payment"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Debit"},
  {"id": 3, "name": "Credit"},
  {"id": 4, "name": "Transaction"}
]
array=array.map(function(item){
  return {[item.name]:item.id};
});
console.log(array);
```

or using `arrow` functions:

```
array=array.map(item=> {[item.name]:item.id});
```

Also, you can use `reduce` function in this way:

```js
let array=[
      {"id": 1, "name": "Payment"},
      {"id": 2, "name": "Debit"},
      {"id": 3, "name": "Credit"},
      {"id": 4, "name": "Transaction"}
    ]
array=array.reduce((arr,item)=>{
    arr.push({[item.name]:item.id});
    return arr;
},[]);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Could you change the `reduce` example to ES6 too.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to use `reduce`? It gets your desired result without it. Just work with [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const types = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "Payment"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Debit"},
  {"id": 3, "name": "Credit"},
  {"id": 4, "name": "Transaction"}
]

const typeArrayMap = types.map((type) => ({ [type.name]: type.id }));
        
console.log(typeArrayMap);

const typeArrayReduce = types.reduce( (array,type)=>{
    array.push({[type.name]:type.id});
    return array;
}, []);

console.log(typeArrayReduce);
```

Using [**Array#reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for aggregate purposes

```js
const people = [
  {name: 'A', age: 7},
  {name: 'B', age: 8},
  {name: 'C', age: 9},
  {name: 'D', age: 10},
];

const sumOfAges = people.reduce( (total, person) => total + person.age, 0 );
console.log(sumOfAges);
```

Comment: I am confused about using only `map` and `map-reduce`  together. Is there a rule of thumb of something that I can read?

Comment: They are different function and have no relation with each other.Basically of you want to get an aggregate result from all items of the array, saying sum of the ages of each people, you can do it with reduce. But if you want to get changed array, use `map`

Comment: In these I am aggregating(I think so) the value in a completely different array, should this be a use case for `reduce`?

Comment: @yadav_vi In this case you get an array of different shapes. With `reduce` you also can do this, but with `map` is simple

Comment: @yadav_vi, `map` is perfectly when you need mapping an array.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` like this:

```js
let data = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "Payment"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Debit"},
  {"id": 3, "name": "Credit"},
  {"id": 4, "name": "Transaction"}
];

let result = data.map((elem) => ({ [elem.name]: elem.id }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't need the `.reduce()` call, because **[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a)** applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to **a single value**.

While **[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array, and that's exactly what you need here.

This is how should be your code:

```
const typeArray = types === null || types.length === 0 ? [] :
  types.map((type) => {
    const id = type.id;
    const name = type.name;
    return {
      [name]: id
    };
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var types = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "Payment"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Debit"},
  {"id": 3, "name": "Credit"},
  {"id": 4, "name": "Transaction"}
];

const typeArray = types === null || types.length === 0 ? [] :
  types.map((type) => {
    const id = type.id;
    const name = type.name;
    return {
      [name]: id
    };
});
    
    console.log(typeArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a combination with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), because the accumulator is always the same and `map` fits better for getting an array with a value for each element, [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the properties and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for the key of a new object.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: "Payment" }, { id: 2, name: "Debit" }, { id: 3, name: "Credit" }, { id: 4, name: "Transaction" }],
    result = data.map(({ id, name }) => ({ [name]: id }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The destructuring makes this answer nice'n clean! +1

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws an exception in Chrome, see:

```js
console.log([1,2,3].reduce((a,b)=>[...a,b]));
```

The reason: `.reduce` has two arguments. The second one is the initial value of `prev`:

```js
console.log([1,2,3].reduce((a,b)=>[...a,b], []));
```

But as others already pointed out: you don't need reduce here. Your sequence is already an array, and even if it wasn't there would be better ways to convert it to an array.

Comment: Who downvote this answer ? It's perfectly correct. Anyway, +1.

Comment: Sure, it's correct, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

One-liner **reduce**

```
const types = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "Payment"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Debit"},
  {"id": 3, "name": "Credit"},
  {"id": 4, "name": "Transaction"}
]


const typeArrayReduce = types.reduce((acc, type) => acc.concat({[type.name]:type.id}), []);

console.log(typeArrayReduce);
```

Comment: Who downvoted this answer ?!  It's perfectly correct (y), but just needs a little more explanation.

Comment: sure, it works, but this is better done with a `.map` than a reduce.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this answer but I thought the question was for **reduce**. Sure you can use **map**: `const typeArrayMap = types.map((type) => ({ [type.name]: type.id }))`. Thank you for the comments.